# Is the 1D Heat Equation with Dirichlet and Neumann Boundary Conditions on the Same Side Well Posed?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, initial-value-problems

If I take the 1D heat equation
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\kappa \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} 
\end{align}
on some finite interval, say $0<x<1$, and then specify Dirichlet and Neumann boundary conditions on the righthand boundary, say
\begin{align}
u(1,t) = C, \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\Bigr|_{x=1} = 0 \, \forall t
\end{align}
along with an initial value
\begin{align}
u(x,0) = f(x)
\end{align}
does this have a well posed solution? I would think not, since I would expect that there would need to conditions specified at the whole boundary (i.e. $x=0$ and $x=1$) for the solution to be well posed. However, that seems odd to me since there is a clear steady state solution for these boundary conditions, as $\partial u/\partial t = 0$ implies that the solution is just $u(x) = C$. Perhaps that's not strange at all, but my experience with PDEs is limited. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It doesn't look like it is.